# Randomnes in fitclinear from Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, random, regression, logistic-regression

I am running a logistic regression using the matlab function fitclinear with the following parameters:

```
rng('default')
[Mdl,FitInfo] = fitclinear(X',y',   'Lambda','auto',...
                            'Learner','logistic',...
                            'ObservationsIn','columns',...
                            'Regularization','ridge',...
                            'Solver','sgd',...
                            'Verbose',1,...
                            'BatchSize',100,...
                            'LearnRate',0.1,...
                            'OptimizeLearnRate',true,...
                            'PassLimit',100,...
                            'ClassNames',[-1,1]);
```

And due to the fact that i m working with recent and long historycal data, I came to realize that training this logistic regression with the exact same X and y and after setting the random generator to default to reproduce results, could results in 2 different results, i.e. 2 different set of Betas and different bias.

Could anyone tell me what could be the reason behing? Where could the randomness come from?

Answer (score 0):

The system starts at a random start point, from there, with the size of your system, there are many local minima which could still be good. The idea is that with larger sizes of frameworks we don't really care about having the same global minima, we care about having decent results. Therefore, we can start at any random point and accept that our system is unlikely to end up with the best result but rather in some location that gives us good results. This means that it is unlikely, given a large system that any two training sequences will be the same.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203288/understanding-almost-all-local-minimum-have-very-similar-function-value-to-the

Comment: yes but buy setting rng('default'), there should not be any randomness anymore between 2 runs  as the random start is the same. Do you agree on that? Therefore the algorithm should converge to the same point isnt it?